# Localization Issue in iOS

Tags: ios

I have app content in English and French language.and sets **localization native development region** is "en" in infoplist. Even though when I change language from French to some other language, not English....it is showing French content in my app, but expected behaviour should be English language ( default language)

Answer (score 1):

The language used by an iOS app is always decided by the iPhone. If your app is localised in French and your iPhone language is French, then your app will be displayed in French, you can't change that.

However, if you app is localised in say English and French and you set your iPhone language to German, then the iPhone will use the *Preferred order for languages* list which you can find in Settings -> General -> Language & Region. The first language in this list that your app supports will be used. So if French appear before English in that list, then your app will be shown in French.

The *localization native development region* is only informative. As the name suggests, it tells you what language the app was developed in, meaning that all other languages are translations from that language. But since it is *en* by default and many people don't change it, it is of little use.

If you need to test your app in a language different than the language of your iPhone, there is an easier way than just changing the language of your iPhone. In Xcode, maintain the alt key pressed and go to Product -> Run. Then go to the Options tab, and you will see an option where you can choose the language your app will run in. Please note that this is only for testing. Once your app is on the App Store, what I have said above applies.